# How do you search for Date in MongoDB GORM

Tags: search, grails, date, mongodb

I cannot do a simple MongoDB search for Date in MongoDB GORM.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You should add what you have tried , what actually failed and the code you tried. that way we can help you out

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to search for Date in MongoDB GORM either. I managed to do this:

```java
import com.mongodb.*

class Foo {
    def fooMethod() {

        Integer interval = 1 * 1000 * 60 * 60
        Date date1 = new Date()
        Date date2 = new Date(date1.getTime() - interval)

        def mongo = new Mongo( "localhost" )
        def db = mongo.getDB('database')
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("collection")
        DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start().put("dateCreated")
        .lessThanEquals(date1)
        .greaterThanEquals(date2)
        .get()

        DBCursor cur = coll.find(query)

        return cur.length()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grails generate methods "findBy..." and "findAllBy..." for field domain model.
Suppose you have domain model.

```
class Foo {
  Date date
}

Foo.findAllByDateBetween(startDate, endDate)
```