# Grails MongoDb findBy

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I'm sure it must be a simple solution but I cannot find it.
I have a grails project with a MongoDb database.
I want to do a find operation. 
Using mongo shell I have:

```
> db.event.find({'author.id':'22'})
```

But I cannot the same thing inside my grails project.
I have tried something like:

```
Event.find(['author.id':'22'])
```

and it gives me no results.
I must do something the wrong way.
My Event domain object has a

```
Map author
```

This is my event collection (a part of it)

```
"_id" : NumberLong(140),
"author" : {
        "id" : "22",
        "realName" : "toto",
        "username" : "rrr"
},
"dateCreated" : ISODate("2014-04-08T20:04:27.054Z"),
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks.
C.C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [low-level API](http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/4.%20Low-level%20API.html) (if you're using "mongodb" plugin):

```
Event.collection.find(['author.id':'22'])
```

Comment: thats the way i´m used to

Answer (score 0):

How i have asked [Grails generate "findBy..." into Domain Model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24802450/3572605), Grails generate "findBy..." methods to fields into domain model.

In you case -

```
Event.findByAuthor(id)
```